# Did "begged" used to have a different meaning?

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context

I was reading the Wikipedia article about [Bella Venezia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bella_Venezia)

> A witch begged every day from the inn, and Bella Venezia promised her
>   half her fortune if she could put an end to the daughter.

It would seem in this context "begged" would mean "take lodge" but after searching on the internet I couldn't confirm this. What does it mean? It doesn't make sense for it to mean "pleaded with". Is it just a typo in the wikipedia article?

Comment: It means she asked for food from the inn. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beg

Comment: English words often have more than one meaning, so it's important to read *all* the definitions within the dictionary entry for the word. Begging for food or money is where we get the English noun "beggar" from.

Comment: @Josh61 isn't the usage wrong, it should be "begged at the inn" not "from the inn"?

Comment: @Celeritas have a look at my comment at my answer

Comment: @Celeritas Some people today work *at* home, or work *from* home.  If your occupation is begging, it doesn't seem strange to beg *from* a place if you're begging *at* that place.

Comment: I agree that "begged from" is usually followed by a person in English. But it's possible that "begged from the inn" was translated word-for-word from the original Italian, explaining the non-optimal choice of preposition.

Comment: From can either refer to the inn as a location, or the establishment. Since you can ask an inn for money/food, as well as ask for money/food inside an inn.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It means *begged* as in *ask for charity*. The original English (from Italo Calvino's *Italian Folktales*, translated from the Italian by George Martin) was:

> Every day an old woman would come to the inn asking for alms, and this old woman was a witch.

The preposition in *begged from the inn* might be better rendered as *begged at the inn*, although you'd have to look at the original Italian to be sure. But *begged* is clearly the correct verb.

Comment: I like _the original_ English, translated _from Italian_ :P But +1 for the research to confirm the meaning.

Comment: It is "from" because she is asking the inn(keeper) for alms. If it were "at" it would imply she were asking all the patrons / passers-by.

Answer (score 7):

I think it just means the witch came for food or money every day. Likely leftover food from the inn.

> beg [VERB]
>   1.1 [WITH OBJECT] Acquire (food or money) from someone by begging:
>   *"a piece of bread which I begged from a farmer"* [(ODO)](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/beg)

**EDIT**: Regarding the quirky preposition, it is likely either a personification of the *business* **inn** rather than the *building* (Thank you AndyT).

Of course the witch doesn't beg from the building, but from a person working there. But to avoid defining that she always begs from the cook or the inn keeper - which isn't important for her as long as someone from the *business inn* gives her food.

As Peter Shor points out in the comments, it is possibly a translated text, so the preposition could stem from a wobbly translation from Italian as well.

Comment: Isn't the quoted sentence wrong as someone begs from a person, not a place or building (the inn in this case)?

Comment: I assume it is a personification of the building inn. Of course the witch doesn't beg from the building, but from a person working there. But to avoid defining that she always begs from the cook or the inn keeper - which isn't important for her as long as someone from the inn gives her food.

Comment: @Helmar - rather than saying it's a personification of the building, I would say it is using "the inn" in the sense of "the business". Much as you might say "Microsoft gave the contract for it's cleaning to Shiny&Clean".